# Failed to load template with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my `index.html` I'm calling scripts `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` version 0.14.3 and below, `angular-ui-router.min.js` version 0.2.15.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" ng-app="main">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular/controllers/carousels.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ui-view="outside"></body>
</html>
```

And in the script `main.js` I call the directives `ui.bootstrap` and `ui.router`.

```
var app = angular.module("main", [
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "ui.router"
]);
```

And that's my route:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

    $urlRouterProvider.when("/", "/home");

    $stateProvider.state("site", {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            "outside@": {
                templateUrl: "./pages/site/index/read.html"
            }
        }
    }).state("home", {
        parent: "site",
        url: "home",
        views: {
            "inside@site": {
                templateUrl: "./pages/site/home/read.html"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But when I go on any page to make call from any element of the *UI Bootstrap*, whether tooltips or carousel, returns me an error saying it can not load the template.
This started after I started using the *UI Router*.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

## -- Edited --

I could finally figure out what is causing the problem.
In the script `main.js` I clean the cache of templates using the following code:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function() {
        $templateCache.removeAll();
    });
});
```

And that is exactly what is causing all my problem.
But how can I clear the cache of templates in *UI Router* without the *UI Bootstrap* stop working?

Comment: The code you provided seems fine, so I think the error is coming from somewhere else; possibly the way you are using dependency injection in the controllers? Would you mind showing some code where you reference it in your controller?

Comment: As I said, this error occurs when I make a call from any element of the UI Bootstrap. Even the tooltips, which does not need a controller.

Comment: How about when you try to configure $urlRouterProvider or $stateProvider? If you have a complex folder structure, its possible that you may have set a templateUrl to a nonexistent location. Do you mind showing that code?